# When i destroy my object create new one in diffrent position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When i click on my mouse button and destroy GameObject i want to create new one on random position, i try instatiate and other methods but it didn't work can someone help me whit this?

```
public GameObject tapObject;
private float respawnTime = 1f;
public float xMin;
public float xMax;
public float yMin;
public float yMax;

void Start()
{     
    StartCoroutine(spawnEnemyTime());
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {           
        Destroy(tapObject);
    }      
}
private void RandomSpawnObject()
{      
    tapObject.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax));
} 
IEnumerator spawnEnemyTime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
        RandomSpawnObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the same GameObject you can avoid destroying it, instead you can control if it's [active or not](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html). It should look like this:

**Edit:**

### Using GameObject.SetActive()

```
public GameObject tapObject;
private float respawnTime = 1f;
public float xMin;
public float xMax;
public float yMin;
public float yMax;

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        tapObject.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(spawnEnemyTime());
    }
}
private void RandomSpawnObject()
{
    tapObject.SetActive(true);
    tapObject.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax));
}
IEnumerator spawnEnemyTime()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
    RandomSpawnObject();
}
```

### Using GameObject.Instantiate()

```
public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject tapObject;
private float respawnTime = 1f;
public float xMin;
public float xMax;
public float yMin;
public float yMax;

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Destroy(tapObject);
        StartCoroutine(spawnEnemyTime());
    }
}
private void RandomSpawnObject()
{
    tapObject = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax)), Quaternion.identity);
}
IEnumerator spawnEnemyTime()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
    RandomSpawnObject();
}
```

Note that when using GameObject.Instantiate(), you need to have a prefab attached.

Comment: It's not work  he deactivete gameobject but  1 sec later he not  activated again

Comment: would you instead set the position, then set it to active?

Comment: i want to deactivate object set new position and then activate again i try setactive not work instatiate also

Comment: Did you try my code @StefanMomcilovic, because when I try it, it does what you need.

Comment: can you follow me on instagram and send me a message to explane my situation lord_stefan_m my instagram and send me message

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to resolve your problem is to create a method and call it with a timer and in that method just use following code

### Code

Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0, Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f));
        Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);

### Note

Instead of using the prefab use you can use the gameobject you are using in the application